# How can I get valuemember from combobox binding with linq?

Tags: c#, linq, combobox, valuemember

How can I get valuemember from combobox binding with linq

```
 cmb_projectName.DataSource = linq1.tbl_Projects.Select(c => new {c.ID,c.ProjectName }).ToList();

int projectID = Convert.ToInt32( cmb_projectName.SelectedValue);
```

cmb_projectName.DisplayMember = "ProjectName";
           cmb_projectName.ValueMember = "ID";

---

```
cmb_projectName.SelectedValue ==> return {ID = 1, ProjectName = "projectname1" }
```

I want to return Just ID value;

What's the problem ??!!

Comment: That's because you did not set the `ValueMember` for your combobox

Comment: Are you sure you set the `ValueMember` to `"ID"`? What about `DisplayMember`, does it show the `ProjectName` correctly for you?

Comment: yes. I set. When i debug my project . show me this value for selected value : {ID = 1, ProjectName = "projectname1" }

Comment: **Please be sure** that you look at **SelectedValue** not **SelectedItem**.

Comment: In the code block you read the selectedvalue before you set the valuemember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong code in your case:

```
cbo.DataSource = StronglyDataTable.OrderBy(x => x.pName)).Select(x => new { x.pID, x.pName });
cbo.DisplayMember = "pName";
cbo.ValueMember = "pID";
```

The correct code:

```
cbo.DisplayMember = "pName";
cbo.ValueMember = "pID";
cbo.DataSource = StronglyDataTable.OrderBy(x => x.pName)).Select(x => new { x.pID, x.pName });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `ValueMember` for your `ComboBox`, otherwise it will be what you saw:

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
//or
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ProjectName";//It's up to you
```

Then the `comboBox1.SelectedValue` will return `ID` or `ProjectName` depending on the `ValueMember` you set, suppose you set it to `"ID"`, so you can get the `SelectedValue` like this:

```
var id = (int) comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```